# Is it possible to accurately log what applications the user has launched through the linux kernel?

Tags: process, linux-kernel

My goal is to write to a file (that the user  whenever the user launches an application, such as FireFox) and timestamp the event.

The tricky part is having to do this from the kernel (or a module loaded onto the kernel).
From the research I've done so far (sources listed below), the execve system call seemed the most viable. As it had the filename of the process it was handling which seemed like gold at the time, but I quickly learned that it wasn't as useful as I thought since this system call isn't limited to user-related operations.

So then I thought of using `ps -ef` as it listed all the current running processes and I would just have to filter through which ones were applications opened by the user.

But the issue with that method is that I would have to poll every X seconds so, it has the potential to miss something if the user launched and closed an application within the time that I didn't call `ps -ef`.

I've also realized that writing to a file would be a challenge as well, since you don't have access to the standard library from the kernel. So my guess for that would be making use of proc somehow to allow the user to actually access the information that I'm trying to log.

Basically I'm running out of leads and I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Sources:

http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x978.html (not very recent)

https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SysCall/syscall-4.html

Comment: Looks like you want to read up about the audit subsystem, which already does all the work.

Comment: @employeeofthemonth Will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

First, writing to a file or reading a real file from the kernel is a bad idea which is not used in the kernel. There is of course VFS files, like /sys/fs or /proc, but this is a special case and this is allowed.
See this article in Linux Journal,
"Driving Me Nuts - Things You Never Should Do in the Kernel" by Greg Kroach-Hrtman
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110

Every new process that is created in Linux, adds an entry under /proc,
as /proc/pidNum, where pidNum is the Process ID of the new process.
You can find out the name of the new application which was invoked simply by 
cat /proc/pidNum/cmdline.

So for example, if your crond daemon has pid 1336, then 
$cat /proc/1336/cmdline
will give 
cron

And there are ways to monitor adding entries to a folder in Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the info!
Will definitely check that article out.